# Automatically Expandable div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have run into a problem. I am trying expand and retract the height of #inner when clicked. When I do this though, I want the height of #container to also increase but without specifying an increase as I did with #inner (+=65px). However, #container does not expand automatically as I thought it would when set to ‘auto’. Can someone please help me with this issue. Would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id=‘container’>
    <div id=‘inner’>This is the inner div</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 function handler1() {
     $(this).css('height', '+=65px');
     $(this).one("click", handler2);
 }

 function handler2() {
     $(this).css('height', ' -= 65px ');
     $(this).one("click", handler1);
 }

 $("#inner").one("click", handler1);
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
#inner {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: A Fiddle would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this code a lot. I stuck with adding css through jQuery since thats how you were doing it but this would be better just using classes. Also added color just so you could see the changes. Instead of adding the overhead of constantly  adding and removing events with `one` we can just use a single handler that tracks the state of the div with a class.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">This is the inner div</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 function handler1 () {
     var inner = $("#inner");
     if (!inner.hasClass('added')) {
        inner.css('height', '+=65px').addClass('added');
     }
     else {
        inner.css('height', '-=65px').removeClass('added');
     }
 }

 $("#inner").on("click", handler1);
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}

#inner {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pv6y6as/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

for me the outer container (#container). does expand too. the problem in your code is that you mix

> ' with ‘

and

> " with “

like here:

```
$(this).css('height', ‘ -= 65px ');
```

or here:

```
$(“#inner").one("click", handler1);
```

so its a syntax problem...

furthermore you should declare classes in html always with " and not with ‘

and never use the rounded apostrophes like you do sometimes :)

also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvs4z91n/)

greetings timotheus

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out, really appreciate it!